# ajax call to PHP data returns VM92:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Can anyone point me in the right direction as of why I receive an unexpected token "}" from this ajax call? I have checked for any extra character to my errors, but I have not found any.  My JSON doesn't validate online, but this doesn't make sense due to me not manually creating the JSON. The error happens in VM98 if that means anything to someone.  Any help would be much appreciated.

```js
$.ajax({
    cache: 'false',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'list.php',
    success: function(result){
        var list = JSON.parse(result);
        console.log(list);

   },
   error: function(){
       console.log('error');
   }
});
```

```php
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM lists";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $json_user = json_encode($row);
        echo $json_user;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: You echo multiply you can create result one array and echo json encode

Comment: I would use `console.log(result);` to see what the JSON looks like before it's parsed. Then try to fix the JSON so it validates.

Comment: Is this exactly how the file looks like? Or are those two separate files?

Comment: The code above is from two separate files.  The JSON is output from the PHP file using json_encode.  It returns this

Comment: {
 "id": "45",
 "item_name": "Juicy Fruit Starburst Sugarfree Gum Strawberry",
 "barcode": "22000017499",
 "image": "http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/XGLhPsn.png",
 "favorite": "checked"
} {
 "id": "43",
 "item_name": "Tostitos Crispy Rounds Tortilla Chips",
 "barcode": "2147483647",
 "image": "http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/7fyPSxH.png",
 "favorite": ""
} {
 "id": "47",
 "item_name": "Kroger Creamy Peanut Butter",
 "barcode": "011110672698",
 "image": "http:\/\/i.imgur.com\/jgC3VKn.jpg",
 "favorite": ""
}

Comment: I think you need some commas in between those `{ }` elements. Also, the whole thing should be in brackets `[ ]` since it's an array.

Comment: How can I add commas when this is an output of json_encode?

Comment: I don't know. It does seem strange that json_encode doesn't produce valid JSON... What is the raw data that is being converted to JSON?

Comment: They're rows from my DB

Comment: I would create an array, make each DB row into an element of the array, then use json_encode on the array. Naumov's comment and gre_gor's answer also suggest this.

Comment: Thanks so much for all of the help! It's working now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are concatenating multiple JSON string together which is not a valid JSON string.

Your JSON looks something like:

```json
{"key":"value1"}{"key":"value2"}{"key":"value3"}
```

You need to put all the rows into an array and encode that into JSON.
Instead of echoing each row in a while loop, you can fetch all the rows in a single call and echo that JSON encoded data.

```php
echo json_encode($result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```

This should produce something like:

```json
[{"key":"value1"},{"key":"value2"},{"key":"value3"}]
```